# Hide delete in odoo 14

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-14

How can I hide the action delete in odoo
[image]

I just want to hide the "Suprimir" action In english is "Delete"

Comment: Do you just want to hide the action or just forbid to delete records (here a delivery slip)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it in form view by inheriting the form view and add attribute `delete="false"` to the form tag.

Find [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/coupon/views/coupon_views.xml#L30) the example for Odoo code for hide (create, edit and delete) in form view.

Find [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/coupon/views/coupon_views.xml#L7) the example for Odoo code for hide (create, edit and delete) in tree view.